# Pan canvas to Reveal Elements when added using D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

4 red `circle`s are first added to the plot, followed by 3 blue `circle`s added to the right. New circles will always be added too the right and the canvas will keep panning to reveal the new circles.

How can the viewable region pan to the right to reveal the new blue circles? The pan should reveal the rightmost blue circle with say 20px of margin between the circle and the edge of the canvas, maybe with a `.transition().duration(1000)`.

It should also rescale in the Y direction to accomodate only the circles in the viewable region after panning.

**Failed Attempt at panning the view** Firstly the pan does not reveal the rightmost circle. Secondly if you were to pan/zoom the view after adding the blue circles, the pan resets to the initial view position before the pan occured.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/YqrLz/4/

**Desired Example**: Pan to right and rescale in Y direction, from

[image]

to

[image]

---

**Update**

After adding the blue circles and panning the chart, the positions of all the cirles look correct relative to each other, but are not correct relative to the axes. In the screenshot below, you can see than circle at x=150 is now at x < 150.

Is there a problem with the code that updates the axis inside `redraw()`?

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ab3zB/3/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I believe you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ab3zB/2/

You're working too hard to get those axis to transition. Think about the axis in terms of your scales. If you update your scale, then simply `.call(yAxis)` on your axis to update them.

The same idea goes with the circles as well. I updated the code to show a more d3-esque pattern to an update. Once you've adjusted those scales, simply redraw the circles, no need to work to compute the actual translation values.

Also your image shows smaller circle radii for the pan. For this, again think about a scale. Create a scale for your radius and then update that scale when you receive new data. Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

Here's a new version that properly scales the radius and position: http://jsfiddle.net/ab3zB/4/ . The problem with the redraw is that it was changing the translate value which was already compensated for when changing the x scale. By removing this it allows the positions to stay consistent.

It gets a bit more tricky when you start using the `d3.event.scale` as a way to scale the `circle` element which isn't tied to the zoom function. `scale` will modify the present translate already applied to it. For example, if it was translated 20 to the right and then you scaled it by 2 it'd also be shifted 40. This quickly makes the code messy trying to adjust for this. An easier solution is this:

```
var r = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, 20])
```

Now you have a scale for the radius and when you update the circle you can simple call `zoom.scale()` to get the current scale value and modify the radius. See the fiddle to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks Benr, I tried your approach and it works great. However as updated in the original post, the alignments of the circles are not correct after adding the blue circles and panning around a little. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what the problem is. When I use the fiddle you posted the first red circle that starts at x=100 stays at x=100 whether you pan or zoom. Is this not the desired behavior? How do I repeat the error?

Comment: Oh I think I see now. If you pan, then add the circles then pan again it break right?

Comment: It's working so well now! I noticed an unexpected rescaling of the view if you were to pan after adding the blue circles. It seems to reset the view to how it was before the blue circles were added. Tried adding `xAxis.scale(x); yAxis.scale(y);` to the `redraw()` function but that did not help...

Comment: Hey, so this has to deal with the fact that zoom automatically sets the x/y domain and is supposed to be responsible for it. Since we set it manually, zoom resets it when it's called again. If you add `zoom.x(x)` and `zoom.y(y)` after we've adjusted the scales it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/ab3zB/6/